# Can not run php artisan migrate command

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I install everything properly but now I need to run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

but when i run that command I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSvT5.png)

What is a problem here?

my laravel.log file say:

```
#8 /var/www/html/laravel3/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(841): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/html/laravel3/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/laravel3/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/laravel3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/laravel3/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('admin');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('hotel');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

this is my user migration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a syntax error. Probably in the create users table migration. Check that file for syntax errors.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your migration file?

Comment: Hey can you run:   find /var/www/html/laravel3/ -type f -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \;   to see if there is any syntax error in another file?  **Sorry this is not going to work on windows**

Comment: My advice is to find a way to "lint" all your php files to look for any syntax errors